# Setting a default value to a param in s:include

Tags: jsp, struts2, jspinclude

I am writing a small widget in struts which I want to include.  The height of the widget should be auto unless I pass in a param of height.  For example:

```
# Example 1:
<s:include value="myWidget.jsp">
  <s:param name="height">300 px</s:param>
</s:include>

# Example 2:
<s:include value="myWidget.jsp">
</s:include>
```

Inside myWidget.jsp I can access the value of height using ${param.height}.  But if I don't pass the height param it simple comes across as blank.  I want to set the value explicitly to "auto", how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [c:out](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/)  in the [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html) core tags.

```
<c:out value="${param.height}" default="auto"/>
```